# I'm doing a student management project in Java and get Serializable Exception errors

Tags: java, exception, serialization, console, notserializableexception

I am doing a basic student management app which runs in console with just 2 functions: Add student and show student list. But I get errors in Serializable Exception though I implements Serialization. My classes as below.

**Class Student**

```java
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Student implements Serializable {

    private String name;
    private int id;
    private int gender;
    private float gpa;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Student() {}

    public Student(String name, int id, int gender, float gpa) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.gpa = gpa;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int isGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(int gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public float getGpa() {
        return gpa;
    }

    public void setGpa(float gpa) {
        this.gpa = gpa;
    }
}
```

**StudenDAO class**

```java
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.io.SerializablePermission;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialException;

public class StudentDAO {
    private static final String STUDENT_FILE_NAME = "studentRecord.txt";

    /**
     * save list student to file
     * @param studentList: list student to save
     */
    public void write(List<Student> studentList) {
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(STUDENT_FILE_NAME));
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(studentList);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            closeStream(fos);
            closeStream(oos);
        }
    }

    /**
     * read list student from file
     * @return list student
     */
    public List<Student> read() throws SerialException {
        List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        ObjectInputStream ois = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(new File(STUDENT_FILE_NAME));
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            studentList = (List<Student>) ois.readObject();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            closeStream(fis);
            closeStream(ois);
        }
        return studentList;
    }

    /**
     * close input stream
     */
    private void closeStream(InputStream is) {
        if (is != null) {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * close output stream
     */
    private void closeStream(OutputStream os) {
        if (os != null) {
            try {
                os.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**StudentManagement** class

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialException;

public class StudentManagement {
    StudentDAO stdao;
    List<Student> list;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public StudentManagement() {
        try {
            stdao = new StudentDAO();
            list = stdao.read();
        } catch (SerialException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void add() {
        System.out.print("Enter student id \t");
        int id = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Enter student name \t");
        String name = sc.next();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Choose gender:\t[male] or [female]?");
        int gender = -1;
        String tempGender = sc.next();
        if(tempGender.equalsIgnoreCase("male")) {
            gender = 1;
        }else if(tempGender.equalsIgnoreCase("female")) {
            gender = 0;
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Enter student GPA \t");
        float gpa = sc.nextFloat();

        Student student = new Student(name, id, gender, gpa);
        list.add(student);
        stdao.write(list);
    }

    //View
    public void showList() {
        for(Student s : list) {
            System.out.printf("%5d %10s %5s %10s \n");
            System.out.printf("%5d %10s %5s %10s", s.getId(), s.getName(), s.isGender(), s.getGpa());
        }
    }
}
```

And this is **Main** class

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StudentManagement management = new StudentManagement();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String choose = sc.next();
        boolean quit = false;
        createMenu();
        while(true) {
            switch(choose) {
            case "1":
                management.add();
                break;
            case "6":
                management.showList();
                break;
            case "7":
                System.out.println("QUIT");
                quit = true;
                break;
            }
            if(quit) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    //Create menu for user's selection
    public static void createMenu() {
        System.out.println("----Menu----");
        System.out.println("1. Add new student.");
        System.out.println("2. Modify student info.");
        System.out.println("3. Sort student by GPA.");
        System.out.println("4. Sort student by NAME.");
        System.out.println("5. Remove student.");
        System.out.println("6. View.");
        System.out.println("7. Exit");
    }
}
```

Then, I end up with these errors
[image]

Comment: "NotSerializableException: Student". Did you add `Serializable` to `Student` without recompiling?

Comment: I tried but It has the same result as above